# Crontab and PHP require_once not working well

Tags: php, batch-file, cron

So I have a cron tab set up

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
  40 14 *  *  * root php /home/sites/sitename/batch/sendemailtest.php
```

Now here is the problem, when I run `php sendemailtest.php` inside the batch directory, everything works fine. But if I run it from any other directory like  `php /home/sites/sitename/batch/sendemailtest.php` it gives me trouble.

I think it's because inside that php file is a `require_once`:

```
require_once '../includes/dbpw.php';
```

So I am guessing the location I call the php file messes everything up.

How do I fix this?

I haven't tried this yet, in fear it will have unintended results... but if I change `HOME=/` to `HOME=/home/sites/sitename/batch/`, then have it run `php sendemailtest.php`, would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cronjob is run from the home directory of the user that the crontab is associated with. There are a couple of ways to get relative paths working correctly from a cronjob like this, but the easiest in my opinion is to just change directories before calling the script.

```
40 14 * * * root cd /home/sites/sitename/batch && php sendemailtest.php
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options:

1. Change the include call to be an absolute file. `include('/home/sites/sitename/batch/scriptname.php')`.
2. Use [chdir](http://www.php.net/chdir) in the top of the php file to change it's working directory. To php this will act as if the script was run from within that directory. In php: `chdir('/home/sites/sitename/batch')`. All scripts after this call will appear as if run from the new working directory.
3. Change the directory in the command like Glen is suggesting.